# How to show response for every controller after token filter is applied

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm currently learning about Spring security and tried to make customer token filter to query the user data from the Bearer Token in header (the token is currently stored in database). But after applying the token Filter the error response or proper response won't show on the response body. What do I need to add to return the response body properly?

```
package com.deeeplabs.psg.config;

import com.deeeplabs.psg.domain.Role;
import com.deeeplabs.psg.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.validation.ValidationException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class TokenAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    UserService userService;

    public TokenAuthenticationFilter(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String accessToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (accessToken != null) {

            String[] myHeader = accessToken.split(" ");

            if (!myHeader[0].equals("Bearer")) {
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
            }

            if (myHeader.length != 2) {
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
            }

            com.deeeplabs.psg.domain.User userData = userService.findByAuthKey(myHeader[1]).get();

            Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
            for (Role role : userData.getRoleList()) {
                grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
            }

            User user = new User(
                    userData.getUsername(),
                    userData.getPassword(),
                    true,
                    true,
                    true,
                    true,
                    grantedAuthorities
            );

            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, user.getAuthorities());
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, "Unauthorized Access");

    }

}
```

This is my current token filter

Answer (score 0):

You must discontinue( return ) from the filter chain once you are sure of the BAD REQUEST.

```
if (!myHeader[0].equals("Bearer")) {
       response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
       return;
}
if (myHeader.length != 2) {
       response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
       return;
}
```

Comment: Does it necessary since the return type is void?

I tried adding this and my postman still doesn't have any response from the localhost , but the error appear on console

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the root cause why the exception won't be shown in response, it's actually I have to add

```
web.ignoring().antMatchers("/error");
```

since Spring Boot by default using server-address/error as error path